# Amazon instance store scheduled for retirement - how to proceed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

We've received an email from Amazon EC2 Service saying one of our servers will be retired in a few days.

I'm new to Amazon EC2, but it appears that due to the fact that it's an instance store, we'll need to create a new image from an AMI and migrate to that.

The questions is, since all the apps on an attached volume, can we just instantiate the new server and attach it to the volume in question? Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Created a new instance based on a similar AMI
2. Terminated the old instance
3. Attached the volume from the old instance to the new instance